# google map API, if possible to search nearby business hot spot?

Tags: google-maps

all, which google map API could be use for search nearby business spot information like ATM/Branch (address and coordinates information etc)

thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This service is provided by Google as part of their [Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/). As of today, it is only a developer preview, and you must have an Adsense account to register.

A `search` request will return up to 20 establishments, which indicate their type, so they can be filtered. There seems to be no way to perform a more direct search by type for now.

Comment: 20 results is a frustrating amount when you compare with their, e.g., "hotel loc: CityName" that returns thousands of results. I would like to get the place marks with as many results as they get using search nearby. :-(